# How to display the data in uibutton when user did select row in pickerview in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am new to iphone i have a small doubt in picker views that is I take a picker view and store some data in it when i select a row in picker view the text in that row should display in uibutton which i have placed but the problem is the first three letters in the text only displays.I dont know why it is this is the code below i have written

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if([pickerView isEqual:selectBookPickerView]){
    NSString *booksTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[booksArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    selectBook.titleLabel.text = booksTitle; 
    }
    else
    {
    NSString *chapterTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[chaptersArray objectAtIndex:row]];
        startChapter.titleLabel.text = chapterTitle; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the width of the text box in Interface Builder? And the size of the font? Expand the width of the box or decrease the font size and your full text will likely show.

Comment: you need to increase the width of the button, because the default width will be 144, so, if you have much bigger sentence, you need to re-frame the button

Comment: 19 questions and none with accepted answer — is clicking the tick so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to put this code after your if statement:

```
[selectBook sizeToFit]
```

This will automatically adjust the button to the size of the text.